# How to make method accept List which contains objects of any datatype

Tags: java

My goal is to check the type of `messages` and then accordingly convert them to Strings and add them. How can I achieve this?

```
public void addMessages(List<?> messages) {
    if (messages != null) {
        if (messages instanceof String) {
            for (String message : messages) {
                this.messages.add(message);
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        for (Object message:messages) {
            this.messages.add(String.valueOf(message));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public void addMessages(List messages) {`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pass in a List of Objects - you don't even need the if/else since you can just always call "toString()" or "String.valueOf" on the message object:

```
public void addMessages(List<Object> messages) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(messages)) {
        for (Object message : messages) {
            this.messages.add(String.valueOf(message));
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note: Potential problems could arise from having null elements in the messages list - so you might want to check for that in your loop. Other potential pitfalls are:

- this.messages is not initialised and adding messages throws a `NullPointerException`
- if this is a method of a singleton (e.g. a spring service) working with instance variables should be avoided

Answer (score 2):

This is just an enhancement over the answers by nutfox.

```
public void addMessages(List<?> messages) {
        List<String> collect = messages.stream().map(i -> String.valueOf(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.messages.addAll(collect);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void addMessages(List<Object> messages) {
```

That is just enough where `messages` hold all type of Objects.

Comment: Then you cannot pass List<Integer> object to this method

Comment: What you mean you can not pass,, Just Now I have passed one.

Comment: @Babel, Java does not allow passing List<Integer> collection to a method that takes List<Object>. The reason being all Integers are Objects. But all objects are not integers. If it is allowed, then you could possibly add a String to this passed collection which violates the constraint that List<Integer> should hold only integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with "Java Generics".

The `Messages` object initialized in the main method below will accept the list of objects of any type. You can initialize `Messages` object with a specific type as well.

```
public class Messages<T> {

    private List<T> messages = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void addMessages(List<T> messages) {
        for (T message : messages) {
            // Use String.valueOf or message.toString() 
            // if you would like to convert the objects to String.
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Messages<Object> msg = new Messages<Object>();
        msg.addMessages(/** Your List of objects of any type **/);
    }

}
```

Comment: what if message is not instance of String. will something like this work:else 
        for(Object message:messages){
            this.messages.add(String.valueOf(message));
        }

Comment: @Tajinder - This is just a sample code to pass the list of objects of any type to a method using Java Generics. I have removed the instanceof check in my answer above. You can write your own business logic to handle the messages. If you want to convert it to string, you can use String.valueOf() or .toString().

Comment: when am trying to fetch data from of return type Message.  default Message recieve() {
  Message message=(Message) rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert();
  return (message) ;

 } . it is giving me warning : Message is raw type

Comment: I believe using wild card will make it run fine .default Message<?> recieve() {
  Message <?>message=(Message<?>) rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert();
  return (message) ;

 }. Am sorry code is not formatted because am new to this.